Which law(s) bans medical exams without a prescription?
I made an appointment for a calcium scan at a local branch of a firm specializing in X-rays, CAT-scans and the like. I knew the procedure is not covered by insurance (I don't know why) and the lady making the appointment reminded me of that again.
When I came at the scheduled time, they asked for a doctor's prescription for the exam, claiming that they "cannot perform it" without such a prescription. When I asked, if this inability is due to their own firm's policy or an actual law, they said -- after some hesitation -- that it is the latter. That no exam can be performed without a doctor's request for same.
No one in the office was able to cite the actual law, which makes me doubtful.
Is it really illegal for an X-ray provider, for example, to take a shot of (or through) your hand without a doctor prescribing it first, or is it simply the corporation's own policy -- created up above to avoid problems with insurance companies who might refuse to pay for non-prescribed exams, and then applied down below (foolishly) even to the procedures that are not covered by any insurance to begin with?
It makes no sense to me,that I can go to a barber for a shave -- which, with the sharp blade next to major blood vessels is much more dangerous than a CAT-scan -- whenever I want but must pay hundreds of dollars for a cardiologist to prescribe a heart-scan before I can have one performed.

Maybe referral, not prescription?

They used the term "prescription"...

A referral is authorization to work with a particular specialist. A prescription is an order for a specialist or pharmacy to provide specific treatment of some kind.

Well, is it required by law -- in New Jersey?

The problem with radiological scans is that damage caused by ionizing radiation accumulates. It doesn't matter if you've been to the barber 1000 times, your next shave is no more risky than the last one. If someone could sign themselves up for unlimited CT scans without any oversight, they could wind up getting several lifetimes' worth of radiation, with each additional scan posing higher risk than the last one. The medical benefit of a scan doesn't always outweigh the risks and requires oversight, but the risk/reward of a shave doesn't require an MD to determine it's a net benefit.

One thought that I have on this is that the technician may need to have additional guidance on what's being sought and that information may be in either the referral or prescription. For example, a primary care physician might request an x-ray of the chest because they suspect fluid buildup in the lungs. The scan will be reviewed by a radiologist who can confirm that suspicion, but will then also advise on other anomalies they see, passing the information to the PCP to provide to the patient in laymen's terms.

If you've already seen the cardiologist or have an upcoming visit, you may be able to contact the office/nurse and ask if the cardiologist can place the order for the scan without a visit.

"is much more dangerous, than a CAT-scan" A CAT scan has an estimated risk of causing cancer of around 1 in 2000. It is dangerous.

AFAIK, in The Netherlands, non-prescribed preventive exams are prohibited by law because they take scarce resources and lead to false positives, which take up yet more scarce resources (and possibly insured costs).

@user71659 going to need a citation for that spicy claim...

@ScottishTapWater Did you Google it? The first Google hit is WebMD which affirms 1:2000. Harvard says 0.7%, and cancer.gov says 1-2 in 10000 for children.

@MooingDuck - The onus isn't on me to find the evidence for your claims

A "prescription" is an alternative term for a "physician's order" or "physician referral". A CAT scan is a type of radiological service.
New Jersey Administrative Code § 10:54-4.21 includes this paragraph:

(i) No radiological services shall be provided in the outpatient
hospital setting without the referral of a physician or other licensed
medical practitioner, acting within his or her scope of practice.


Thank you! I wonder, if NY has a similar law... I really hate to pay the cardiologist for two visits.

@MikhailT. To the best of my knowledge, the only radiology exception in NY is for screening mammograms, no physician order required. CAT scans of any kind are almost certainly restricted because of the high radiation dose. Physicians are supposed to review the patient's medical record for other radiation exposure before ordering a CAT scan. NY also allows medical tests by a lab without a prescription if any over-the-counter, at-home test for the same condition or substance has been approved by the FDA.

If this is just a case of the cardiologist having forgotten to issue said referral, a call to the office will probably suffice, that's just an admin problem.

NY also allows medical tests by a lab without a prescription if any over-the-counter, at-home test for the same condition or substance has been approved by the FDA. So someone (not sure who actually want to do such a thing) could get a colonoscopy without a referral because it is a screen for colon cancer and so is Cologuard?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Nah, a colonoscopy is a procedure, and you can't go to lab like Quest Diagnostics to get one. I think the goal of the NY law is that a person who does an OTC at-home test can have it repeated by a lab (without a doctor's order) for confirmation of the results if they have any doubts about accuracy.

Hmm; I wonder how it would go if I said I need a DICOM image of my own hand bones for software development purposes.

@Joshua: In your case, this would be a non-medical x-ray.  Thus, it would fall under different regulations.  E.g., the law cited in this answer is specific to hospital settings.  Of course, a provider operating under a hospital setting (as was the case for OP) would be obliged to say no.  Mind you, non-medical x-rays are internationally discouraged due to health concerns.

@Brian: I am reasonably convinced the safest way to do it is to throw that rule in the trash. Why? Because the medical safety protocols are going to be so much better than the non-medical safety protocols. (It's possible to view this as if you're going to insist this boneheaded thing it's still better to have the real professionals do it than some fly-by-night operation.)
